# multiply-accumulate using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I have the following loop in python3 with numpy array:

```
for s in range(ns):
    dens += f[:,:,s]
    momx += ex[s]*f[:,:,s]
    momy += ey[s]*f[:,:,s]
```

i would prefer to vectorize this for-loop. The first line could be rewritten simply as:

```
dens = np.sum(f,2)
```

The last two lines are a multiply-accumulate operation but i don't know how to implement this in a vectorized way. I have been looking at [`np.ufunc.accumulate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) but this seems to do something else than i want. Who has a good idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your original question, you could have two approaches, one with `matrix-multiplication` using [`ndarray.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dot.html) and another using [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), like so -

```
momx = f.reshape(-1,f.shape[2]).dot(ex).reshape(f.shape[:2])
momx = np.einsum('ijk,k->ij',f,ex)
```

You can use similar strategies to find `momy`.

---

For a modified case, where you might want to use `f[s,:,:]` instead in places where you had `f[:,:,s]`, the modified solutions would be -

```
momx = ex.dot(f.reshape(f.shape[0],-1)).reshape(f.shape[1:])
momx = np.einsum('ijk,i->jk',f,ex)
```

---

Runtime tests and verify outputs -

```
In [573]: def org_app(f,ex):
     ...:     ns = f.shape[2]
     ...:     momx = np.zeros(f.shape[:2])
     ...:     for s in range(ns):
     ...:         momx += ex[s]*f[:,:,s]
     ...:     return momx
     ...: 

In [574]: f = np.random.rand(9,512,512)
     ...: ex = np.random.rand(f.shape[2])
     ...: 

In [575]: np.allclose(org_app(f,ex),f.reshape(-1,f.shape[2]).dot(ex).reshape(f.shape[:2]))
Out[575]: True

In [576]: np.allclose(org_app(f,ex),np.einsum('ijk,k->ij',f,ex))
Out[576]: True

In [581]: %timeit org_app(f,ex)
10 loops, best of 3: 44.8 ms per loop

In [582]: %timeit f.reshape(-1,f.shape[2]).dot(ex).reshape(f.shape[:2])
100 loops, best of 3: 4.8 ms per loop

In [583]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,k->ij',f,ex)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.84 ms per loop
```

Comment: Can you roughly indicate what the performance of the `reshape` and `einsum` methods are compared to my original `for-loop`? Currently i am experiencing that the vectorized code is actually slightly slower than my original `for-loop`.

Comment: @nluigi What are the shapes of the input arrays that you are using?

Comment: `f.shape` is currently [9,128,128], but i will go to larger array e.g. [9,512,512].

Comment: @nluigi Not sure about your benchmarking procedure, but I have just added mine based on [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html). And the vectorized approaches are winning by huge margins!

Answer (score 2):

```
momx = np.sum(ex*f, 2)
```

There are also a few other tools you could use, such as `einsum`.

Comment: What about if the index is switched to `f[s,:,:]`?

Comment: @nluigi: Add some extra length-1 axes to `ex` to line things up: `np.sum(ex[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]*f, 0)`.